# How to setup Svelte project for importing component from TS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte

I ran the `scripts/setupTypeScript.js` script from the Svelte starter, but I'm being unable to import component from a TS. If I rename my entry point script `EntryPoint.ts` to `EntryPoint.js`, I successfuly import a Svelte component (the IDE resolves the reference), otherwise the IDE reports that the component doesn't exist. As I understand, the starter should have resolved this issue, so am I missing simple settings in Rollup configuration?

Component import:

```js
import EntryPoint from 'app/ui/EntryPoint.svelte';
```

TS configuration:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "app/*": ["./src/*"]
        },
        "types": ["createjs"]
    },
    "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",

    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules/*", "__sapper__/*", "public/*"]
}
```

Rollup configuration:

```js
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import includePaths from 'rollup-plugin-includepaths';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

let includePathOptions = {
    include: {
        'app': 'src/app',
    },
    paths: [],
    external: [],
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.ts', '.svelte']
};

export default {
    input: 'src/EntryPoint.ts',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'wwwroot/build/bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        includePaths(includePathOptions),
        postcss({
            extract: true,
        }),
        svelte({
            preprocess: sveltePreprocess(),
            // enable run-time checks when not in production
            dev: !production,
            // we'll extract any component CSS out into
            // a separate file — better for performance
            css: css => {
                css.write('wwwroot/build/bundle.css');
            },
            customElement: true,
        }),

        // If you have external dependencies installed from
        // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
        // some cases you'll need additional configuration —
        // consult the documentation for details:
        // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: importee => importee === 'svelte' || importee.startsWith('svelte/')
        }),
        commonjs(),
        typescript({
            sourceMap: !production,
            inlineSources: !production
        }),
        // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
        // the bundle has been generated
        !production && serve(),

        // Watch the `wwwroot` directory and refresh the
        // browser on changes when not in production
        !production && livereload('wwwroot'),

        // If we're building for production (npm run build
        // instead of npm run dev), minify
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};

function serve() {
    let started = false;

    return {
        writeBundle() {
            if (!started) {
                started = true;

                require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                    stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                    shell: true
                });
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rollup's setup seems outdated, try to install the latest version of svelte using degit

`npx degit sveltejs/template my-svelte-project`

then execute this command

`node scripts/setupTypeScript.js`

Comment: I've created a new project as you demonstrated, but I'm still unable to import Svelte from TS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this is neccessary on TS configuration:

```json
{
    "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",
}
```

And my current TS configuration overrides `compilerOptions.types`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types": ["createjs"]
    },
}
```

The solution is to include `'svelte'` in `compilerOptions.types` array.

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types": ["svelte"]
    },
}
```